# Google Earth Engine - concatenate 'year' to iterate over a function

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I wanted to iterate a function taking year as an argument to get my desired Landsat collections per year. I'm concatenating argument 'yr' and iterating using .map function.

An _.concat is not a function error appears.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

-Nands

```
var per_year = function(yr){
    var start = '-01-01';
    var end = '-12-31';

    var collect = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_RT_TOA")
     .filter(ee.String(yr).concat(start), ee.String(yr).concat(end));

    return (collect);
}

var years = ee.Array(ee.List.sequence(2006, 2012));
print (years);

var year_list = years.map(per_year(years));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to map over an `ee.List` object that has all of the years, call the Landsat image collection in the function, and cast the results to an image collection.

```
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_RT_TOA")
var years = ee.List.sequence(2013,2017)

var yearlyCollections = years.map(function(i){
    i = ee.Number(i)
    var date = ee.Date.fromYMD(i,1,1)
    return landsat.filterDate(date, date.advance(1,'year')
})

print(yearlyCollections)
```

The result should be a `ee.List` object with the same number of image collection as years.